# OOP Reuse without Inheritance: How "real-world" practical is this?

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition

This article describes an approach to OOP I find interesting:

> What if objects exist as
>   encapsulations, and the communicate
>   via messages? What if code re-use has
>   nothing to do with inheritance, but
>   uses composition, delegation, even
>   old-fashioned helper objects or any
>   technique the programmer deems fit?
>   The ontology does not go away, but it
>   is decoupled from the implementation.

The idea of reuse without inheritance or dependence to a class hierarchy is what I found most astounding, but how feasible is this?

Examples were given but I can't quite see how I can change my current code to adapt this approach.

So how feasible is this approach? Or is there really not a need for changing code but rather a scenario-based approach where "use only when needed or optimal"?

EDIT: oops, I forgot the link: here it is [link](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/39/)

Comment: Can we have link to the original article?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sure you've heard of "always prefer composition over inheritance".

The basic idea of this premise is multiple objects with different functionalities are put together to create one fully-featured object. This should be preferred over inheriting functionality from disparate objects that have nothing to do with each other.

The main argument regarding this is contained in the definition of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and playfully illustrated by this poster:

[image: Liskov Substitution Principle: If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, but needs batteries - you probably have the wrong abstraction]

If you had a ToyDuck object, which object should you inherit from, from a purely inheritance standpoint? Should you inherit from Duck? No -- most likely you should inherit from Toy.

Bottomline is you should be using the correct method of abstraction -- whether inheritance or composition -- for your code.

For your current objects, consider if there are objects that ought to be removed from the inheritance tree and included merely as a property that you can call and invoke.

Answer (score 7):

Inheritance is not well suited for code reuse. Inheriting for code reuse usually leads to:

1. Classes with inherited methods that must not be called on them (violating the Liskov substitution principle), which confuses programmers and leads to bugs.
2. Deep hierarchies where it takes inordinate amount of time to find the method you need when it can be declared anywhere in dozen or more classes.

Generally the inheritance tree should not get more than two or three levels deep and usually you should only inherit interfaces and abstract base classes.

There is however no point in rewriting existing code just for sake of it. However when you need to modify, try to switch to composition where possible. That will usually allow you to modify the code in smaller pieces, since there will be less coupling between the classes.

Answer (score 4):

I just skimmed the text over, but it seems to say what OO design was always about: *Inheritance is not meant as a code reuse tool and loose coupling is good.* This has been written dozens times before, see the linked references on the article bottom. This does not mean you should skip inheritance entirely, you just have to use it conciously and only when it makes sense. The article also states this.

As for the duck typing, I find the examples and thoughts questionable. Like this one:

```
function good (foo) {
  if ( !foo.baz || !foo.quux ) {
    throw new TypeError("We need foo to have baz and quux methods.");
  }
  return foo.baz(foo.quux(10));
}
```

What’s the point in adding three new lines just to report an error that would be reported by the runtime automatically?

Comment: Inheritance is often overused, but sometimes it is really powerful and elegant to do implementation inheritance. A language which does not have inheritance is not OO, period.

Answer (score 4):

## Inheritance is fundamental

no inheritance, no OOP.

prototyping and delegation can be used to effect inheritance (like in JavaScript), which is fine, and is functionally equivalent to inheritance

objects, messages, and composition but no inheritance is object-based, not object-oriented. VB5, not Java. Yes it can be done; plan on writing a lot of boilerplate code to expose interfaces and forward operations.

Those that insist inheritance is unnecessary, or that it is 'bad' are *creating strawmen*: it is easy to imagine scenarios where inheritance is used badly; **this is not a reflection on the tool, but on the tool-user**.